# geany 1.32 - change color of bracket matching 18.10 MATE

Tags: geany

In this version the highlight for matching brackets is dark blue which against a black foreground font is not a significant highlight. Ubuntu 18.10 MATE.

How can I set this to a brighter color?

Web query results haven't much for geany on this topic. The solution given here https://lists.geany.org/pipermail/users/2015-December/009843.html does not work for me. The filetypes-common file does not have a [named-styles] section so I added one.

This has no effect. Is there an updated solution, or is there something else amiss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit [geany-themes](https://github.com/geany/geany-themes/). The README describes how to download and install color schemes for Geany 1.22 upwards.

Once that's done, in Geany, *View > Change Color Schemes …* will allow you to scroll through available color schemes such that you can see the effect of each theme on how matching occurs.

In the image below, I've opened `/etc/skel/bashrc` and placed the insertion cursor immediately to the right of one `}`. With the *Slush and Poppies* theme, both `}` and the matching `{` are highlighted. The same applies to `{}` and `()` pairs.

[image: Geany color schemes]

Comment: I have posted this solution with additional comments to the unix stackexchange group where I had originally posted this question. 
  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493309/geany-1-32-change-color-of-bracket-matching/495301#495301